# Adding grpof -pg Options Makes My Multithreaded Application Non-multithreaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, gprof

I'm trying to profile the performance for my multithreaded application.

So I added "-pg" option when compiling it.

I'm using a fixed number of threads in the thread pool: if there are 4 CPU cores, there will be 12+1 = 13 threads running.

The big surprise to me is that after I added "-pg" option, there is only one thread running, and the other threads are not running at all (status "S" in `top` command).

```
top - 12:16:03 up 2 days, 21:46,  4 users,  load average: 1.02, 1.07, 1.32
Tasks:  13 total,   1 running,  12 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.6%us, 25.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 73.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   9224140k total,  5070060k used,  4154080k free,   214480k buffers
Swap:  9431164k total,        0k used,  9431164k free,  1722216k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 3252 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.32 MyMultithreaded
 3251 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 R   99 26.0  12:02.83 MyMultithreaded
 3250 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.01 MyMultithreaded
 3249 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:02.88 MyMultithreaded
 3248 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.12 MyMultithreaded
 3247 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.14 MyMultithreaded
 3246 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.46 MyMultithreaded
 3245 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.32 MyMultithreaded
 3244 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.16 MyMultithreaded
 3243 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.27 MyMultithreaded
 3242 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.12 MyMultithreaded
 3241 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:02.87 MyMultithreaded
 3240 plee      20   0 3111m 2.3g 3292 S    0 26.0   0:03.23 MyMultithreaded
```

So is there any solution to this?

Does this have anything to do with:
http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html

Thanks.

Peter

Comment: BTW, I tried using gprof-helper (http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html), still same behavior, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed and tried OProfile, it works okay, and it can also give you the gprof-style results.

```
opgprof ./bin/MyProgramBinary  # Generate the gmon.out file
gprof -p ./bin/MyProgramBinary > gmon.txt
```